# Power BI: Plot not showing complete data

Tags: plot, powerbi

I am using a ribbon chart to visualise total sales over 3 years, using `Product ID` as legend.

Then in another bar graph I plotted total sales by `Product ID`.

What I observe, is that when I click on the top `Product ID` values in the bar graph, some did not appear in the ribbon chart accordingly(it should be as it's reasonable to assume that total sales over the 3 years by `Product ID` is correlated to total sales each year by `Product ID`). In addition, some top `Product ID` values in the ribbon charts also did not appear in the bar chart accordingly.

Note:

1. I checked to make sure that the "missing data" in ribbon chart can actually be found in the data using the filter function.
2. I replaced the ribbon chart with a stacked column chart and the results are the same.
3. Both plots used the same table and columns.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When there are too many values

You will see a logo on the plot:

[image]

Hovering your cursor on top, it'll read:

> Too many values. Not showing all data. Click to see details.

So you have to filter by top N, for example to select the most important values to show.